# TCL pipe filehandle to avoid disk-access slowdown

Tags: pipe, tcl, disk

I am running an EDA product. This product gives an API, which input I would like. However, the output is submitted to a file-handle. I.e.:

```
getFooData -elem <elem to query> -query <what is queried> -fh <file handle>
```

This means that if I want to do more crunching, I need to read what is input in the file handle, after the writing process is finished, or risk an O(2) algorithm.
The data can be enormous, and our filer system is slow/overloaded/out-quota (or a combination).
Is there a way for me to "catch" the data that should be output to the file handle, by creating some file-handle which does not output anything to the file system? Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
getFooData -elem <elem to query> -query <what is queried> -fh $fh
set m [ getLatestInputOfPipeFh $fh ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option (Tcl 8.5 and later) would be to create a "reflected channel", which is an in-memory channel.   The wiki page listed below has complete examples.

Assuming that your EDA product is still stuck on 8.4 (which is quite old), you will need to use a standard file or pipe.

You don't mention what operating system you are on.  On unix you can create a named pipe.  While this will use the filesystem, the file should stay small enough that it stays in memory all the time.

```
proc processFooInput { fh } {
   set data [gets $fh]
   # process data
   if {[eof $fh]} {
      fileevent $fh readable {}
   }
}

set pfn /tmp/fooData
exec mkfifo -m 0666 $pfn
set outfh [open $pfn w]
set infh [open $pfn r]
fconfigure $infh -blocking 0 -buffering line
fileevent $infh readable processFooInput
getFooData -elem <elem to query> -query <what is queried> -fh $outfh
```

Apparently Windows also has named pipes accessed via an internal API, so they're a bit harder to use (and I've never used them).

If you don't have a named pipe, you will probably need to use a file:

```
set sfn /var/tmp/fooData.tmp
set outfh [open $sfn w]
set infh [open $sfn r]
fconfigure $infh -blocking 0 -buffering line
fileevent $infh readable processFooInput
getFooData -elem <elem to query> -query <what is queried> -fh $outfh
```

References: [refchan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/refchan.htm); [wiki: reflected channel](https://wiki.tcl.tk/17594); [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm); [fileevent](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/fileevent.htm); [fconfigure](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm)

Comment: If there's a lot of data being produced, it may be simpler to just use a lot of disk space.